# Get E-Mail domain name of official email IDs

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap

I am currently writing a program for an E-mail system app. In that app, users can sign in with an email account of any domain. For personal email ids, I am using the following code to get the domain name:

```
String[] temp = emailId.split("@");
temp = temp[1].split("\\.");
return temp[0];
```

But this method wouldn't work for official email ids like: name@collegename.edu.in. It is necessary to find email domain names to find appropriate IMAP and SMTP servers for reading and sending mail. How can we find email domains for such email ids.

Comment: Why are you splitting on dots at all?  What is your desired output?  Why not use something like thunderbirds ISPDB?

Comment: @Max What I have done is that I have stored SMTP and IMAPs of different email domains like gmail, outlook, gmx, etc. in a HashMap. So i split the email id with '@' and '.' and get the domain. Eg: if email id is: abc@gmx.com. After splitting I will get gmx as the value. Then I will get IMAP and SMTP value corresponding to gmx mail from the HashMap. Then I will use those SMTP and IMAP values in JavaMail to define Property of email account, like property.put("incomingHost", HashMap.get("gmx").

Comment: There are older questions about this over the years, try searching.

Comment: Well, the domain of `gmail.com` is `gmail.com`, not just `gmail`. Because for example, there is a domain such [gmail.it](https://www.gmail.it/), and it is still an email provider because Google never bought this domain and someone used it before to leverage on the name. I think the issue is simply that your map should not contain "gmail" as key, but "gmail.com" which is the real domain. And when that's the case, then you could simply split by the "at" ignoring the dots as @Max is suggesting.

Comment: P.s note that if someone had `matteo@gmail.it` as mail address, your code would find `gmail` and would use the IMAP/SMTP of `gmail.com`, which would turn out being wrong for the mail address you received (what you would have wanted, instead, was to throw an exception to say that domain `gmail.it` is not supported). So I really think your map should contain the full domain name as key.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thank you. Will change my code accordingly